# Sum of Numbers Exercise, Python 3

Tags: python, sum

Any help would be much appreciated. I am new studying Python. Here is the exercise I have to complete. I have seriously given this about 3 to 4 hours of my time so no worries that I am "asking someone to do my work for me." Here is the exercise and what I have so far. I have been puzzling these out and "hacking" my way through the learning process. If you know the whole code and don't mind including it, I would very much appreciate it.
EXERCISE: Write a program with a loop that asks user to enter positive numbers. Users should enter a negative number to signal the end of the series. When the user ends the program (by typing in a negative number) the sum of the positive numbers should be displayed. Here is what I have so far.

```
# The main function.
def main():
# Variable to control the outer loop.
another = 'y'
while another == 'y' or another == 'Y':
    numbers()
    another = input('Run this program again?\n\
Enter y for yes.')
def numbers():
positive = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
while positive > 0:
positive = int(input('Enter a positive number, or enter a\n\
negative number to end and calculate the sum: '))
positive = int(input('Enter a positive number: '))
while positive < 0:
for i in range (positive):
    print(i)
# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: Please tell what the problem is. Is your indentation correct?

Comment: Please re-format the code. I tried to do that for you but failed to decieper it. By the way, you do not store entered numbers in any place (p.ex. a list of entered values or cumulative sum would be handy). Also, do you know what `range` function does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
# The main function.
def main():
  mysum = 0
  while True:
    positive = int(input('Enter a positive number, or enter a\n\
negative number to end and calculate the sum: '))
    if positive < 0:
      print mysum
      return
    mysum = mysum + positive

# Call the main function. 
main()
```